# making a ajax call to populate scope data in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

Hello i have a angular js controller like this

```
function InstantSearchController($scope){

$scope.items = [
    {
        url: 'http://tutorialzine.com/2013/04/services-chooser-backbone-js/',
        title: 'Your First Backbone.js App – Service Chooser',
        image: 'http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/service_chooser_form-100x100.jpg'
    }
];
```

}

and i have a ajax call

```
function getListOfJsonObjects(){
$.ajax({
    url:"http://"+window.location.host+"/getListOfJsonObjects",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader("JSESSIONID",  $.cookie("JSESSIONID"));
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        foreignKeyType:"OrgChartJSon",
    },
    success:
        function(dataFromServer){
        var parsedJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(dataFromServer));                  

    },
    error:
        function(xhr, status, error){

        alert("Failed");
    }
});
```

}

how can i make a $http.jsonp call inorder to put response data into scope items. 
please help i tried with the call `var responsePromise = $http.jsonp(url, {params : {foreignKeyType:"DecisionTreeJSon"} } );`
even thought response status is 200 it always entered into failure method.

angular code:

```
<div ng-app="instantSearch" ng-controller="InstantSearchController">

<div class="bar">
    <!-- Create a binding between the searchString model and the text field -->
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
</div>

<ul>
    <!-- Render a li element for every entry in the items array. Notice
         the custom search filter "searchFor". It takes the value of the
         searchString model as an argument.
     -->
    <li ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString">
        <a href="{{i.url}}"><img ng-src="{{i.image}}" /></a>
        <p>{{i.title}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your full Angular code instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use jQuery at all in AngularJS projects.

You must use $http $resource services to query webservices.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/euovbo?p=info) to show how to use $http to fill the scope, it is not jsonp but you should easily extends this example.

Comment: if i use $http i get XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://getListOfJsonObjects/?foreignKeyType=JSon. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. error